# How do I get access to the http headers added to the dialogFlow handleRequest

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am writing a DialogFlow service.

My service receives DialogFlow fulfilment requests via an API gateway that is inserting some additional authorization headers that I need to pick up in my service.

I am using the DialogFlowApp handlerRequest method in my code but I cannot get access to the headers from the requestHandler.

The headers are added to the handleRequestMethod in the usual way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/google", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleGoogle(@RequestBody String form, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        try {
           jsonResponse = google.handleRequest(form, getHeadersMap(request)).get(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Resposnse "+e);
        }
        return  jsonResponse;
    }
```

I have tried accessing the headers using something like this:

```
public ActionResponse genericIntentHandler(ActionRequest request) {
       Argument a = request.getArgument("someval");
       //Or
       Object b = request.getParameter("someval");
}
```

Neither of these work.

Looking at the code on github, the request handler seems to add the headers to the AogRequest class

https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/google/actions/api/impl/AogRequest.kt

However, the specific function called to create the class seems to do nothing with the headerMap in the constructor.

Could someone please help.

Comment: You have access to the headers before passing them into your intent handler class.

getParameter and getArguments aren't used to access HTTPS headers.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Odd thing is that you can add them to the intent request but they are not accessible from inside the request.  I wonder what is the purpose of adding them.